# Present UIViewController at startup for an animating launch screen in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, launch-screen

I have a UISplitViewController for the rootViewController !

**I don't know how to present a UIViewController for the animated launch screen !**

In AppDelegate.swift I have:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController

    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 1.0
    splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 360

    splitViewController.delegate = self

    return true
} ...
```

**Where and how can I present a UIViewController in full screen "over" the  UISplitViewController ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ViewController as rootViewController for window to show it in fullscreen mode. After that you can turn back SplitViewController for window.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ViewController that is inside that SplitViewController you can call:

```
let newVc = ViewController() //change this to your class name
self.splitViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In the MasterView or in DetailView of UISpitViewController ?